# Why do hyperlinks break the line? Any solution for it?

Tags: php, html, css

a line of code contains several hyperlinks, i want output as a single line but it doesn't work.

I also used css

```
           a {white-space:nowrap; }        it doesn't work.
```

line of code is:

```
<a href="profile.php?v=<?php echo $uid;?>"><?php echo $uname;?></a>made offer for your task:<a href="task1.php?t=<?php echo $task_id;?>"><?php echo $tasktitle;?></a>says,"<?php echo $comment; ?>"<br/>
```

Output i'm getting:

```
                    David Jackson 

                    made offer for your task:

                    paint on walls

                    says,"hello..i'm agree!"
```

Output i expected:

```
 David Jackson made offer for your task: paint on walls says,"hello..i'm agree!"
```

Comment: You should post actual HTML code (as received by a browser) with CSS code, such that it reproduces the problem. The code posted does not do that, when the PHP commands are replaced by data strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have `a{display:block}`

Change it to:

`a { display:inline }`

Comment: now i changed it to

a{ 
white-space: nowrap;
display:inline
}

still no effect, is there any fault in css file?

Comment: Do you have any other CSS rules or other CSS stylesheets? Maybe a rule somewhere is overriding it. Try using `a{ display:inline !important}` and check. If it works, then a rule somewhere is taking precedence. You should find out where.

Comment: i found that, it was in #menu a{display:block}, i tried a{ display:inline !important},it overriding that rule.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No its not compulsory to anchor tag will break the line, its also depend on editors also, and if this is also not working so use this

a { display:inline }.

Answer (score 0):

Because the < a > < / a > standard value is

```
"display:block;"
```

you should try

```
a {display:inline}
```

Comment: Anchors are not blocks by default.

Comment: a element is not block by default: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A

Comment: oh well, my bad. Always thought the anchor default was block. Well learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
a{ display:inline !important} and check.

This will override other css rules for anchor tag ().